# Omnet++ How to connect up a network in my application

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to build a simple simulation using omnet++. I'd like to avoid using things like ned. Instead I want to allocate the modules set up the simulation topology entirely under program control. (i.e. I'll configure my simulation and set up connections etc. in main() instead of using ned)

How do I go about doing this ? (any examples you can point me to?)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a top level network in NED and drop a single simple module called `builder` or something like that. Then create/connect the necessary modules in that module's initialize method (or schedule a message at t=0s and do the network buildup there).

There is an example in OMNeT++ that does exactly like this, in samples/routing. Choose the `NetBuilder` configuration. That example is reading the network topology from an external file, but you can change it to create any topology you would like to have.

The actual code for the network generation is in samples/routing/builder/netbuilder.cc in `NetBuilder::buildNetwork`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.